# langchain sqlagent reply with wrong result

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, sql-agent

I have a simple SQLagent which queries a database with id and email address on a table.
I want to check if there is a matching email and reply with id. if no match reply with none.

If there is a match, it works fine, but if there is no match, but there is  a closer matching email, it returns the random value from the ID column. For example if there is a match for myFirstName.Lastname@mydomain.com it works, but if I pass in myFirstName.Lastnam**A**@mydomain.com it will return a random ID.
Any idea on how to fix this?

```
``*dburi = "sqlite:///data/users.db"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(dburi)
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=OpenAI(temperature=0))

agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
)

agent_executor.run("What is the id for email is exactly myFirstName.Lastname@mydomain.com. I want 100% match ignoring the case. If you can not find it reply with NONE")*`
`
```

If there is a match, it works fine, but if there is no match, but there is  a closer matching email, it returns the random value from the ID column. For example if there is a match for myFirstName.Lastname@mydomain.com it works, but if I pass in myFirstName.Lastnam**A**@mydomain.com it will return a random ID.

Comment: I'd say if you have such a specific case of finding a record with an email, why even use an LLM to generate that query for you? Just write and run it yourself? If on the other hand that prompt is coming from a user I don't really see anything you can do there since the user can throw all sorts of prompts at you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the query and sort this out.
My new query is:

```
agent_executor.run("Do you have a record with email is myFirstName.Lastname@mydomain.com. I want 100% match ignoring the case. If you have a match reply with the ID. If you can not find it reply with NONE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code with minor tweak based on your requirements

```
        dburi = "sqlite:///data/users.db"
        db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(dburi)
        toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=OpenAI(temperature=0))

        custom_suffix = """
            Filter the records based on exact match, ignore similar search or close matched records
        """

        agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
            llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
            toolkit=toolkit,
            verbose=True,
            agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
            suffix=custom_suffix
        )

        agent_executor.run("What is the id for email myFirstName.Lastname@mydomain.com")
```